# NuxtJS Firebase V9 modular in service worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, nuxt.js, service-worker

Firebase documentation says to use this code inside service worker:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getMessaging } from 'firebase/messaging/sw'
```

But I get this error:

```
Token error: FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker.
```

I assume that this is because WebPack under NuxtJS configuration ignores "import" inside service worker files.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @SRR

No, but I used compat version:

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.0/firebase-app-compat.js')